# Oracle query fine tuning

Tags: oracle, query-optimization

Hi I have a database with large number of records roughly, 400K which is supposed to grow even more.

I have a query to fetch data from this table to display records to user . my query is below.

```
    SELECT  "PC0".PYID   AS "pyID" ,
  "PC0".NAME                 AS "Name" ,
  "PC0".OPPORTUNITYSTAGE     AS "OpportunityStage" ,
  "PC0".PXCREATEOPNAME       AS "pxCreateOpName" ,
  "PC0".PZINSKEY             AS "pzInsKey" ,
  "PC0".OPPORTUNITYSHORTNAME AS "OpportunityShortName" ,
  "PC0".IDTYPE               AS "IDType" ,
  "PC0".IDNO                 AS "IDNo" ,
  "Campaign".PROGRAMNAME     AS "ProgramName" ,
  "Campaign".ENDDATE         AS "EndDate" ,
  "PC0".PRODUCTNAME          AS "ProductName" ,
  "PC0".PRODUCTTYPE          AS "ProductType" ,
  "PC0".OPPORTUNITYSTAGE     AS "OpportunityStage" ,
  "PC0".PXCREATEOPNAME       AS "pxCreateOpName" ,
  "PC0".OPPORTUNITYSOURCE    AS "OpportunitySource" ,
  "PC0".OPPORTUNITYOWNER     AS "OpportunityOwner" ,
  "PC0".IDTYPE
  ||"PC0".IDNO                                                          AS "pyTextValue(1)" ,
  "PC0".REMINDERDATE                                                    AS "ReminderDate" ,
  "PC0".STAGELASTCHANGED                                                AS "StageLastChanged" ,
  ROUND((CAST(SYSDATE AS DATE) - CAST("PC0".STAGELASTCHANGED AS DATE))) AS "pyIntegerValue(1)" ,
  (
  CASE
    WHEN ROUND((CAST(SYSDATE AS DATE) - CAST("PC0".REMINDERDATE AS DATE))) > 0
    THEN 1
    WHEN ROUND((CAST(SYSDATE AS DATE) - CAST("PC0".STAGELASTCHANGED AS DATE))) > 7
    THEN 2
    ELSE 3
  END)                                                              AS "pyIntegerValue(2)" ,
  "PC0".PXCREATEDATETIME                                            AS "pxCreateDateTime" ,
  "PC0".CAMPAIGNID                                                  AS "CampaignID" ,
  ROUND((CAST(SYSDATE AS DATE) - CAST("PC0".REMINDERDATE AS DATE))) AS "pyIntegerValue(3)"
FROM MYCO_OPPORTUNITY "PC0"
LEFT OUTER JOIN MYCO_CAMPAIGN "Campaign"
ON ( "PC0".CAMPAIGNID = "Campaign".PYID)
ORDER BY 21 ASC,
  22 DESC
```

This takes near to 13 seconds to fetch first 50 records in SQl developer. In real time I will be fetching almost 5k records at a time.

The time 13 sec is coming after i have defined functional index for CAST on REMINDERDATE and STAGELASTCHANGED column and a bitmap join index.

Can you please suggest how should i optimize the query. Order by on a large set might be an issue bit it is must for me. :(

Comment: Show us explain plan and check if indexes are used.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux we need to fetch sorted results. like first the records which has passed reminderdate, then which are not followed up for more than 7 days and then the others.

Comment: Let see if I understand it well: when you disable the funct. index, you have decent performances. When it is enabled, it is way too long? If it is so, could you compare both execution plans? In addition, is there a way for you to reproduce that behavior on a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we could be able to test it?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux No Sylvain. Iwa nt to reduce the time takesn to retrieve results. Intially i was getting 18sec. i defined two functional indexes and now i get 13 sec. Is there a way? we can reduce further. Order by seems to be the culprit as i get result in 1 sec if i remove 'order by'. But my business needs ordered data !!

Comment: you can't optimize a query before figuring out what a bottleneck in your query is. this is your first goal. take a look at this article - it has the basics https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_interp.htm#TGSQL94618. After your post your execution plan with statistics - we probably would be able to help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an index on:  "PC0".CAMPAIGNID  and on:  "Campaign".PYID

Make sure your SGA is set high enough.  Without knowing a lot information about the server and database it's hard to provide guidance other than make sure the SGA is large enough.

Answer (score 0):

You're using "order by" on a computed column, which means Oracle has to compute this value for all 400k rows, before being able to sort and return results. To be certain that this is the problem test without using order by.

<strike>There are a number of possible solutions but this example does not seem to be your actual use case so its pretty much meaningless to suggest optimizations for it</strike>.

Without more knowledge about the data I'd suggest splitting the query into three parts connected with union and implement indexes on reminderdate and stagelastchanged.

```
select * from ( [part 1] where reminderdate > sysdate order by pxCreateDateTime ) 
union all
select * from ( [part 2] where reminderdate <= sysdate and stagelastchanged + 7 < sysdate order by pxCreateDateTime ) 
union all
select * from ( [part 3] where reminderdate <= sysdate and stagelastchanged + 7 >= sysdate order by pxCreateDateTime )
```

I'd then expect that 1. and 2. should be satisfied using index and 3. a full table scan, which might be helped by adding a first_rows hint.

Comment: It is my actual use case. I need to fetch result first the records which have passed reminder date , then records which are not followed up for 7 days and then the rest. So is the code..

ROUND((CAST(SYSDATE AS DATE) - CAST("PC0".REMINDERDATE AS DATE))) > 0

WHEN ROUND((CAST(SYSDATE AS DATE) - CAST("PC0".STAGELASTCHANGED AS DATE))) > 7

Comment: So you're not limiting the selected results in any additional way?

Comment: 'No' as of now; but may go by limiting the max no of reocrds to 5000 based on performance of the query.